# Doctrine: Object of class User could not be converted to string

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I keep getting this error with Doctrine:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class User could not be converted to string in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 1337
```

In my system users can have many permissions in a One to Many relationship. I have set up a `User` and `Permission` entity. They look like this (I removed some annotations, getters and setters to reduce clutter):

```
class User {

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    */
   protected $id;

   public function getId()
   {
      return $this->id;
   }

   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Permission", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
    */
   protected $permissions;

   public function getPermissions()
   {
      return $this->permissions;
   }

}

class Permission {

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="permissions")
    */
   protected $user;

   public function getUser()
   {
      return $this->user;
   }

   public function setUser( $user )
   {
      $this->user = $user;

      return $this;
   }
}
```

The problem occurs when I add a new `Permission` to a `User`:

```
$permission = new Permission();

$user->getPermissions()->add( $permission );

$em->persist( $user );
$em->flush();
```

This is the last bit of my stack trace:

```
PHP  11. Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->persist() vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:565
PHP  12. Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->doPersist() vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1555
PHP  13. Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->cascadePersist() vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1615
PHP  14. Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->doPersist() vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:2169
PHP  15. Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->persistNew() vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1597
PHP  16. Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->scheduleForInsert() doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:836
PHP  17. Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->addToIdentityMap() vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1157
PHP  18. implode() vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1337
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a check, did you remember to run `doctrine:schema:update` ? :)

Comment: what is the `add` method code?

Comment: @IgorPantović: Unfortunately I can't do this. I'm applying Doctrine to an already existing database. Sorry, should have mentioned that.

Comment: @shad: The `add` method is from Doctrine's `ArrayCollection`, i.e. `getPermissions()` returns an `ArrayCollection`. I have updated my question with my persist code though..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your solution gave me a clue of what is happening.

Even though you have the entities and the anotations, Doctrine  is not being able to understand the relation between entities. When doctrine understands the relation between entities, it knows what methods to call (ie User::getId())  but otherwise, it tries to transform whatever you are sending to a scalar value that it can use to query the database. Thats why it is calling the __toString function of the User, and thats why if you return the id in toString, everything works from here.

This is ok, but its a patch, and probably you dont want to keep  it if we can find a better solution, since it could be harder to maintain as your application grows.

What i can see, is that in Permissions you have:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="permissions")
*/
 protected $user;
```

You should remove the `@ORM\Column(type="integer"`)

About the join columns, it is not mandatory, but you have to be sure that the defauts, are what you want. As we can read [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#mapping-defaults)

> Before we introduce all the association mappings in detail, you should
>   note that the @JoinColumn and @JoinTable definitions are usually
>   optional and have sensible default values. The defaults for a join
>   column in a one-to-one/many-to-one association is as follows:

```
name: "<fieldname>_id"
referencedColumnName: "id"
```

so, they will be the same as an explicit:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="permissions", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
  protected $user;
```

So it is supposed to look for a column `user_id` in the `Permissions` table, and join it with the `id` column of the `User` table. We suppose that this is ok.

If this is true, then in your User, the id shouldnt be user_id, but id:

```
 /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    */
   protected $id;
```

Or if the column name is actually user_id, then the User class is ok, but you have to change the join column to  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")

That much i can say. I cannot try it know, but i will be glad if you can give it a second.

Answer (score 13):

OK. I've got it working.

I haven't fully worked out the reason yet but when I add the following to my `User` entity it works:

```
class User {    

   public function __toString()
   {
      return strval( $this->getId() );
   }

}
```

If I find out more I will post here.

Comment: I just encountered the same issue and this seems to fix it, but it's still a big question mark to me why Doctrine even needs this when the entity has the @Id annotation on the identifier property.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a problem with the mapping of user property in permission entity. Try this one:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="permissions")
 * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
```

Comment: I tried this. Cleared my cache and all but I get the exact same error.

Comment: check your getters on both entities to see if there's an object returned instead of variable, eg. `return $this;` instead of `return $this->id;`

Comment: I've added my getters and setters to the question. I don't see anything wrong with them...

Answer (score 0):

are you initializing the collection in your OneToMany side?
and also, the methods to add and remove from the collection?

```
class User {
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Permission", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
    */
   protected $permissions;

   public function getPermissions()
   {
      return $this->permissions;
   }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->permissions = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }



    public function addPermissions (Permission $permissions)
    {
        $this->permissions[] = $permissions;

            return $this;
     }


     public function removePermissions(Permission $permissions)
     {
        $this->permissions->removeElement($permissions);
      }

       //...
```

Comment: Hi. Yes my `$permissions` are initialized with an `ArrayCollection`. Not sure how the `add` and `remove` methods on the entity contribute the question.

Comment: actually the only thing I was concerned about was the constructor. The other methods could be convenient, but i like to do it since i like the  entities to have a consistent interface, not depending on the implementation of its data types. Also, what i know is that if you create your entities by reverse engineer from database, with the doctrine tools, those methods are created, i dont know if this means that some hydrators are expecting them to be there.

Comment: No worries. Point taken.